# asp core 2 mvc does not respect pattern or template or route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have that route that I want to execute the controller action only if all parameters are in the url. But when I go to the url without the parameters, it shows the action page. It should return a 404 error code automatically.

I know the default route is the problem. But I don't know how to fix it without having doing `if(param == null) return NotFound();`

Here is my route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home_AddVoucher",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id:int}/{price:decimal}/{from:regex(^\\d\\d-\\d{{2}}-\\d{{4}}$)}/{to}/{passengers:range(1, 9)}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "AddVoucher" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home_getPrice",
        "{controller}/{action}/{productId}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "getPrice" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");


});
```

I want all the `AddVoucher` route parameters to be provided to call the controller action.

The controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddVoucher(int id, double price, DateTime from, string to, int passengers)
{
    AddVaucherModel addVaucherModel = new AddVaucherModel();


    return View(addVaucherModel);
}
```

Comment: Quick suggestion: is it ok to have a separate controller for voucher and price? They do not sound like "home" concepts anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's ok to have a separate controller for voucher and price. But I  still gonna have the same problem.

Comment: I'm gonna try putting addVoucher and price in a separate controller and replace the {action} texts by hard texts like get/price to see what happens.

Comment: I expect 404 to kick in correctly since you are accessing a route outside HomeController which is linked to the default route.

Comment: I changed them in a new controller. But it still showing the action without parameter. Here are the routes `routes.MapRoute(
                    "Voucher_getPrice",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{productId:required}",
                    new { controller = "Voucher", action = "getPrice" }
                    );` At the end I have the default route that causing the problem `routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");`

Comment: What happens is that, like `/Voucher/getPrice` does not match the route `Voucher_getPrice` so it goes to the default `default` route and it does match. Is there an attribute I can use on my action controller to say it to not get execute when the parameter is not provided?